# Vue child component wait for props

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a parent component that's passing a prop (selectedOption) to a child component, and the child component takes the prop and renders an icon based on the prop. But every time I load the page, the child component throws an error because the prop has not been passed down in time, but it's fine after a second when everything is passed down. How can I avoid this?

Parent (Settings.vue):

```
<template>
    <settings-menu
      :selectedOption="selectedSettingsOption">
    </settings-menu>
```

Child (SettingsMenu.vue):

```
<template>
  <component
    :is="`icon-${ selectedOption }`">
  </component>
</template>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just put a v-if to hide the component until the prop gets passed.

```
<template>
  <component
    v-if='selectedOption' :is="`icon-${ selectedOption }`">
  </component>
</template>
```

Comment: Lot of times Vue has a simple solution for the regular problems :)

Comment: What if one  of my props is conditional? 

VideoOptions(v-if="video" :video="video" :user="user ? user : null")

Comment: @robertfoenix the v-if part can take any JS expression. So you can make the if check as sophisticated as you want. v-if="video && user && isValidUser(user)" etc.